# using core bluetooth framework did discover peripherals delegate method is not getting called by itself in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

Following is my code which i have written.I found many similar question but could not get proper answer helpful to me.
I am using swift and ios 8 for working and using core bluetooth Did discover peripheral method should be called by itself but is not getting called. what should I do to resolve?

**code**

[image: Code which I have implemented using core bluetooth framework]

[image]

Comment: Please post real code instead of screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are invoking `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` immediately after creating the `CBCentralManager` - You need to wait until the central manager is in the powered on state.

ie -

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {

...
   else if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn {
       central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil,options:nil)
   }
...
}
```

Also, in future you should post your code into your question and use the **{}** icon to mark it as code rather than inserting images, as images makes it impossible to copy your code into an answer

**UPDATE**

Your other problem is that you are creating your `CBcentralManager` as a local variable inside your `btnScanClicked` so as soon as this method ends your `CBCentralManager` will be released.  You need to create it as a property on your class and then refer to `self.central`

Comment: Still your suggestion is not working please suggest other solution for this.